# dom not updating when object is changed

Tags: svelte

I have what I believe is a quite small and simple svelte webapp, which is currently just a questionnaire. And I am trying to create a sort of multiple select system, where you can click a bunch of buttons and have them marked as selected (pretty much an html checkbox but it is slightly beside the point).

So in order to show to the user that an option is selected, I want to add a class to button if it is selected. However it is not being updated, and I can't really figure out why.
The `isSelected` function is only called once per option and never when the setup object is modified, and I am wondering why that is

```html
    <script>
      let page = 0;
      let setup = {
        JLPT: {
          question: "select JLPT levels",
          options: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
          selected: [],
          onSelect: option => {
            console.log(setup.JLPT.selected);
            setup.JLPT.selected = setup.JLPT.selected.concat(option);
          }
        }
      };
      $: question = getQuestion(page);
    
      function getQuestion(page) {
        return setup[Object.keys(setup)[page || 0]];
      }
    
      function isSelected(option) {
        return (question.selected || []).indexOf(option) > -1;
      }
    
      function onClick(option) {
        getQuestion(page).onSelect(option);
      }
    </script>
    
    
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="question">{question.question}</div>
      <div class="input">
        {#each question.options as option}
          <button
            on:click={() => onClick(option)}
            class={isSelected(option) ? 'selected' : ''}>
            {option}
          </button>
        {/each}
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace `$: question = getQuestion(page);` with:

```
$: question = setup[Object.keys(setup)[page || 0]];
```

https://svelte.dev/repl/f7c2a4119829442a8e46ebb557bf1cf8?version=3.29.4

### Why?

The way **Reactive declarations** work, is that svelte parses it and extracts the parameters it depends on. In the case of `$: question = getQuestion(page);` the dependencies are `getQuestion` and `page`, and whenever any of them changes, `question` will be recomputed.

But `getQuestion` and `page` never change, so `question` is never recomputed.

So what you want, is `question` to be recomputed whenever `setup` changes, and to do that you need to make sure `question` depends on `setup`.

In other words, you need the **Reactive declarations** to have this form

```
$: question = ...setup...
```

---

That principle also happens in this line

```
class={isSelected(option) ? 'selected' : ''}
```

Svelte parses it, and extracts as dependencies `isSelected` and `option`, and recomputes the "class attributes" whenever any of them changes.

But now you might think ... *Hey! but they never change, so how is this even working?*.

The reason is that `option` is part of the `#each block` that depends on `question` which in turns depends on `setup`.
So whenever `setup` changes (marked as "dirty") `question` is recomputed and marked as "dirty", and thus each "class attribute" is recomputed because indirectly they all depend on `question`.

---

**BTW**: a better solution to assign classes dynamically is using [the class directive](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/classes)

```
class:selected={isSelected(option)}
```

---

You might want to read this post https://lihautan.com/compile-svelte-in-your-head-part-2/#reactive-declaration to get a better feeling of what Svelte is doing under the hood in **Reactive declarations**